# Discord.NET Trying to get SocketUser as SocketGuildUser returning null

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am working on a C# Discord.Net bot, and have come across an issue I thought I had previously resolved.
I need to get the user mentioned in the message as a '*SocketGuildUser*'. This works perfectly fine when I attempt it on my own user. However, it wasn't working on my friend's user. While it could get a '*SocketUnknownUser*', it failed to get a '*SocketGuildUser*', just returning null. After I removed a certain role from them, the bot worked completely fine for a couple of days. However, all of sudden, it has now stopped being able to get a '*SocketGuildUser*' from my friend's user, with no changes to the relevant code.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var userToModCheck = message.MentionedUsers.ElementAt(0);
var userToMod = message.MentionedUsers.ElementAt(0) as SocketGuildUser;
```

*userToModCheck* returns the correct username and user ID, but as a SocketUnknownUser. *userToMod* returns null.

So far, I have tried:

- Checking the bot 'Privileged Gateway Intents' permissions in the Discord developer portal
- Using a separate function(*Context.Guild.GetUser*) to get the *SocketGuildUser* using the user ID
- Changing roles
- Restarting both computers
- Searching the internet

**Edit:** There are no issues when the mentioned user is online and has the online status. Very strange.
**Edit 2:** Switching 'AlwaysDownloadUsers' to true does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Are your friends still on the server ?

Comment: The user is probably not in cache. Set AlwaysDownloadUsers to true in the discord socket config

Comment: Anu6is I tried this, but it unfortunately didn't work. Do users have to be online when the client connects for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'DiscordSocketConfig' wasn't configured properly. Firstly, make sure all 'Priveleged Gateway Intents' are enabled in the Discord Developer Portal. (*Application* > Bot).

Change 'AlwaysDownloadUsers' to true, and 'GatewayIntents' to all, then apply it to the client:

```
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig{ AlwaysDownloadUsers = true, GatewatIntents = GatewayIntents.All };
_client = new DiscordSocketClient{config};
```

The bot then works properly.

Comment: You shouldn't need all intents. You should only enable the intents that you require.

Comment: Please include code as text, not screenshots. Can you [edit] your answer to accommodate this? That will improve readability, searchability, and accessibility.